# Adjust position on window scroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a plug-in that launches a modal dialog on a page. It is positioned in the center, by utilizing boxPosition(el) function.

```
function boxPosition(el) {

    // calculate/set height of content area         
    var winH = $(window).height(),                          // viewport height
        winW = $(window).width(),                           // viewport width


    // position modal in center
    var boxH = $('#myModal').outerHeight(true),         // real modal height
        bmcH = ttlH + auxH + cntH + ftrH + 80,             // modal height plus content padding/margin  
        bmcW = $('#myModal').outerWidth(true),              // real modal width 
        bmcT = (winH - (boxH < bmcH ? boxH : bmcH)) / 2,   // top offset for centering          
        bmcL = (winW - bmcW) / 2;                          // left offset for centering 

    $('#myModal').css({ 'top': bmcT+'px', 'left': bmcL+'px' });
}
```

When I load the page or when the page is resized the functioned is called within this plug-in:

```
boxPosition(el);

$(window).resize(function() {
    boxPosition(el);
});
```

I'm trying to address two more issues:

1. I'd like to keep it centered also on pages that a lot of content and can scroll. I've tried this but it does not seem to be working.

   $(window).scroll(function () {
       boxPosition(el);
   });
2. I'd like to call that function when any click within the modal is registered.

Comment: sounds like you know what you'd like to get done, which is good. the first step to achieving your goal is setting one. let us know how it ends up!

Comment: Did you mistype the name of the function at the top, or is it actually `boxPos` instead of `boxPosition`?

Comment: if it it's a model dialog, why not do what i do. I always set a command on "open" of a modal dialog to hide overflow of `html, body`. Then on whatever "close" event, I reset `html, body` to `overflow: ''` which of course removes the inline styling of the overflow. I usually use jQuery in combo with jQueryUI Dialogs to do this if you'd like an example.

Comment: That's a great idea. I just tried -- works great and a lot more elegant. Thanks. That solves my issue #1.